# Cross validation on random forest

Tags: machine-learning, random-forest, cross-validation

I did random forest regressor and cross validation with the code below.

I have two questions.

- I don't understand what "scores" mean in cross validation in the case
  of Regression, not classification(I mean in the case of default).What
  is this?
- And are there functions to set other function(such as
  mean_squared_error) as scores?

Thank you.

```
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor

rf = RandomForestRegressor(n_estimators=100, criterion='mse',random_state=1, n_jobs=-1)    
rf.fit(X_trainr, y_trainr)    
y_train_pred = rf.predict(X_trainr)    
y_test_pred = rf.predict(X_testr)    
y_all_pred = rf.predict(xsetr)    

from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score

scores = cross_val_score(rf, xsetr, ysetr, cv=5)    
print("Cross-validation scores:{}".format(scores))
```

Answer (score 1):

- It gives you the accuracy of your model on the validation set
- But it performs Kfold cross-validation and not a simple training-validation split
- **[Cross-Validation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-validation_(statistics))** is usually applied when you have very less data and it usually the split is turn by turn
- The number of cross-validation split is given by parameter `cv` which in your case is 5
- It simply means that there will be split of the data 5 times (with different splits each time)  and model performance on this split will be evaluated and this evaluation measure is the accuracy
- The `scores` variable will be a numpy array of float whose shape will be (5, )
- So your `scores` array contains 5 values and each value represents the accuracy of your model for on a particular split (the split is the test data)
- The scoring parameter does not necessarily be accuracy you can set it to a MSE or any other quantitative measure
- You can change the `scoring` parameter which has to be a string of the `cross_val_score` function but I think by default it is accuracy
- You can check **[here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html#scoring-parameter)** list of scoring parameters

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation: the results of cross_val_score is **Array of scores of the estimator for each run of the cross validation.**. By default, from my understanding, it is the accuracy of your classifier on each fold. For regression, it is up to you, it can be mean squared errors, a.k.a. loss. If you have interests, you can go through the source code of this function.

Answer (score 0):

The default score used in sklearn for regression models is the [R^2 coefficient.](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestRegressor.html#sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestRegressor.score)

> The coefficient R^2 is defined as (1 - u/v), where u is the residual
>   sum of squares ((y_true - y_pred) ** 2).sum() and v is the total sum
>   of squares ((y_true - y_true.mean()) ** 2).sum(). The best possible
>   score is 1.0 and it can be negative (because the model can be
>   arbitrarily worse). A constant model that always predicts the expected
>   value of y, disregarding the input features, would get a R^2 score of
>   0.0.

You can choose a different cv score by passing a [scoring parameter](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html) to cross_val_score. For minimizing mean squared error, it would be neg_mean_squared_error (scores are always maximized):

```
scores = cross_val_score(rf, xsetr, ysetr, cv=5, scoring = 'neg_mean_squared_error')
```